# jenkins with ldap : Test LDAP settings show two groups for user

Tags: jenkins, ldap, ldif

LDAP side:
I have associated users to groups with **gidNumber**. Example for group and users as part of my ldif file:

```
dn: cn=jenkins-administrators,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: jenkins-administrators
gidNumber: 5000

dn: cn=jenkins-users,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: jenkins-users
gidNumber: 5001

dn: uid=dude-user1,ou=Employee,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: dude-user1
sn: Dude
givenName: Dude
cn: Dude dude
displayName: Dude dude
uidNumber: 1000
gidNumber: 5000
userPassword: 123456
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/dude-user1
mail: dude-user1@gmail.com

dn: uid=dude-user2,ou=Employee,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: dude-user2
sn: Dude2
givenName: Dude2
cn: Dude2 dude2
displayName: Dude2 dude2
uidNumber: 1001
gidNumber: 5001
userPassword: 123456
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/dude-user2
mail: dude-user1@gmail.com
enter code here
```

Jenkins side: I have installed LDAP plugin and configured ldap Security Realm:

[image]

But when I run `Test LDAP settings` it shows that the user belong to **two groups**:

[image]

I expect to see only one group assosiate with the user.

any Idea what I do wrong?
I really whant to keep ldif file as is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mixed things more than I should.

just need to add `memberUid: user.name` to the groups in LDIF file.
Once doing so, no need to config `Group search filter` and `Group membership`